# Advantages and disadvantages of using population and samples for statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sample, population

I need to know the advantages and disadvantages of using a sample or a population to collect data. I understand what a sample is and what a population is, but I do not know what the advantages and disadvantages would be. Can someone help?

Comment: You probably mean "census" instead of "population," for otherwise this question makes no sense. For closely related threads please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31981 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21403.

Comment: Maybe this will also help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167972/why-is-there-a-need-for-a-sampling-distribution-to-find-confidence-intervals/167998#167998

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Population:**

*Advantages*:

1. No need for sampling! (The entire population is in your dataset)
2. Your findings would be representative of the population (since your analyses are based on the population).

*Disadvantages*:

1. To collect all of the information for a population it would likely take a great deal of time, which means more effort and money.

---

### **Sample:**

*Advantages*:

1. Usually the only option - it would be a rare scenario to have data on an ENTIRE population.
2. You can make reliable estimates of the population with less time, effort, and money. (If the sample is representative of the population of interest)

*Disadvantages*:

1. None, as long as the sample is representative of the population of interest. Otherwise, bias aplenty! And bias means that you will have some explaining to do!

---

As you can see, the advantages of the population are in regards to having all the information that you would ever want; however, sampling is usually the reality as a function of time, effort, and most importantly, money. By ensuring adequate sampling from the population of interest, a representative sample can be extracted to perform analyses and identify findings that one would uncover while looking at the entire population at a fraction of the cost.

Comment: The disadvantages to using a population is just because the cost would be higher and it is very difficult to get 100% of your data. Where as for a sample you are able to get 100% of your data because you are only using a subset from the population?

Comment: Correct! Once you have your sample, you have your data, and if it is representative, you can make sound inferences using that sample that can be utilized to better understand the population as a whole.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question I just want to recap here so the advantages for a population is that all your data would be right there. As long as you have the time and money. And the disadvantage would be costly and time consuming. Advantages of a sample is it is easier and more possible to collect the data by using a subset rather than the whole population and it is less costly.

Comment: Exactly! Well learned! :)

Comment: Thanks :) I am not great in statistics well any type of math for that matter. So I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Saying that there is "none" disadvantages of using sample rather than population is a bit too optimistic... Also, there are cases where obtaining whole population is cheap and easy. IMHO you simplify things a little bit too much. Another advantage of population is no need for statistics: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2628/35989

Comment: Obtaining the whole population will almost always be more "expensive" than gathering a representative sample - whether it is time or money - and if it isn't, just gather the whole population and one would not need to ask the question about what are the advantages and disadvantages of samples and populations.