# How do I report a 95% CI in a one sample t test?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

How do I report a negative 95% CI in a one sample t test? What does this mean?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167972/why-is-there-a-need-for-a-sampling-distribution-to-find-confidence-intervals/167998#167998

Answer (score 3):

A one-sample $t$-test is a test of whether your observed mean is equal to some pre-specified null value (usually $0$).  That is equivalent to seeing if the 95% CI for your observed mean includes the null value.  They want you to report a 95% CI for the mean of your data.

Comment: (+1) except for the last sentence. The CI is for the true mean, not for the mean of the data.