# How to find se.fit by hand? in R

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I´m trying to find by hand the se.fit. I have 30 different values of the Y real and the Estimate Y. How can I calculate it? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Martina.  Could you be more specific about what "the se.fit" might be?  It sounds like you might mean one of the (many) standard errors associated with some form of regression, but what form and which standard error?  Also, are you aware you can search our site for answers?  I find many formulas for ordinary least squares regression, for instance, by searching [least squares formula standard error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=least+squares+formula+standard+error).  Also, please try to apply more appropriate tags: this is not a question about mathematical statistics.

Comment: Thanh you for your answer! I´m talking about the standard error for individual linear regression predictions. I've been looking on your website for answers but I couldn't find the right one.

Comment: I added "prediction" to the search terms and found answers: see the duplicate.  You can also find the formula quoted in an image in the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187601 and in the thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560077.

Comment: Thank you very much!