# Completely understanding the Confidence Interval - how is it not a probability of containing a population parameter?

Tags: probability, parameterization, confidence-interval

I've been doing data analysis for a while, but recently I questioned my understanding of the oft-misunderstood confidence interval.  So, I read multiple sources.

Many of them say explicitly that the confidence interval is `NOT the probability that a specific confidence interval contains the population parameter`.  Rather, it is the `percentage of times a confidence interval will contain the population parameter after many samples.`

I honestly can't tell the difference between these:  Isn't the latter the same as the probability?  If not, how is it different?  I suppose the definition of `probability` might be throwing me off here.

Here's one of the sources I used:  http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/understanding-hypothesis-tests%3A-confidence-intervals-and-confidence-levels

Comment: Please try reading [this Cross Validated page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6652/28500), which is directly on this topic, and edit your question if you need further clarification on specific issues.

Comment: see section 3 of this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167972/why-is-there-a-need-for-a-sampling-distribution-to-find-confidence-intervals/167998#167998

Comment: @Candic3 In response to your paragraph "I honestly can't tell the difference between these: Isn't the latter the same as the probability? If not, how is it different?": Both statements are indeed probabilities, but they are probabilities of different things. In the correct definition, the probability refers to the confidence intervals; in the incorrect definition, the probability refers to the parameter. (I've got more detail in the Day 2 slides at http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/CommonMistakes2015/commonmistakeshome2015.html)